# Not able to confiugure HTTPS in Tomcat using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7, tomcat8

I have configured the HTTPS in tomcat in Netbeans by following below steps but when I am trying to access the site via HTTPS then I am getting error "Secure Connection Failed". Please help

1) Generate the key

```
   keytool -genkey -alias Crunchify -keyalg RSA -keystore
```

2) Copy the Key `<tomcat installation dir>`/Conf directory

3) Modify the server.xml file

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="conf/.keystore" keystorePass="password" maxThreads="25" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

4) Open the project web.xml and added the below tag under `<web-app>`

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Constraint2</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am not sure if this is a problem but something similar was happening to me the problem was that tomcat is looking for alias tomcat in provided keystore and fails if there isnt any. So try step 1 with alias tomcat